# is there a way in java to, while a method is running, detect an integer change and run said method, then return to the same spot

Tags: java

I am currently creating a text adventure game and am displaying the player stats through the Jtable. I want to use the Jtable repaint method in order to make it display the stats as they change however I don't want to have to write the repaint method after every time I change it. How could I run the repaint() method whenever a stat changes and then continue with the rest of the code.

Here is the script running the Table that the repaint listener must be added:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainSystem extends JFrame{

    public static class Stats{
        public static int x = 1;
        public static int n = 0;
        public static ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>(n);
        public static int karma;
        public static int SPC;
        public static int OPC;
        public static int wisdom;
        public static int billsProposed;
        public static int billsPassed;
        public static String party;
        public static String currentBill;
    }

    public static JTable statsWindow;

    public mainSystem() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {"Stat", "Value"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{"Karma", Stats.karma}, {"SPC", Stats.SPC}, {"OPC", Stats.OPC}, {"Wisdom", Stats.wisdom}, {"Bills Proposed", Stats.billsProposed}, {"Bills Passed", Stats.billsPassed}, {"Party", Stats.party}};
        statsWindow = new JTable(data, columns);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(statsWindow));
        this.setTitle("Stat Window");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void addToContacts(String name){
        Stats.n = Stats.n + 1;
        Stats.contacts.add(name);
    }

    public static void table(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new mainSystem();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        while (Stats.x == 1){
            int karmaChange = Stats.karma; int SPCChange = Stats.SPC; int OPCChange = Stats.OPC; int wisdomChange = Stats.wisdom; int billsProposedChanged = Stats.billsProposed; int billsPassedChanged = Stats.billsPassed;
            intro.Introduction();
            Section1.section1();
            break;
        }
        if (Stats.x != 1){
            End.loose();
        } else{
            End.win();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the observer  pattern, and it is not automatic:

- You must create a listener interface (see for example `ActionListener` or `MouseListener`) with a method to be called when the `int` property change (hint: you may use [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)).
- You must be able to register listener to your observable object. You may look at `addXXXListener` from any `JComponent` object (for example: [addPropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addPropertyChangeListener-java.beans.PropertyChangeListener-) or [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)). Registering is basically adding listener to a list of listener to "warn".
- When you change the `int` value, you have to fire the event, cycling through the listeners bounds to your object. You can read the code of [`DefaultListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) for an example.

As for your question title:

> Is there a way in java to, while a method is running, detect an
>   integer change and run said method, then **return to the same spot**

Unless you are running in several thread, if all you are doing is done on the same thread, then you will return to the same spot. Then again, you are using Swing, and you have the main thread and the `EventDispatchThread` (EDT): you may need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` (if you are not on the EDT) to return to the same spot.